# How to create multidimensional array from php post?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

how to create multidimensional & associative array from php post?

```
        $html .= '<td><input id="location" name="location['.$i.']" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-solid" placeholder="result data (kosongkan jika tidak diperlukan)" value=""/></td>';
        $html .= '<td><input id="msg" name="msg['.$i.']" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-solid" value="' . htmlspecialchars($key) . '"/></td>';
        $html .= '<td><input id="order_id" name="order_id['.$i.']" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-solid" value="' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '"/></td>';
```

i want to make array output like this:

```
[$_POST['location'] => [$_POST['msg']=>$_POST['order_id']]]
```

Comment: Ok, so what is stopping you.

Comment: `$val = $_POST['location'];
   $arr = [];
   for($i = 0; $i <= $val; $i++)
    {
        $arr[] = [$_POST['location'][$i] => [$_POST['msg'][$i] => $_POST['id'][$i]]]; 
    }

    
exit(var_export($arr));`

only show results null

`array (
  0 => 
  array (
    '' => 
    array (
      '' => NULL,
    ),
  ),
)`

Comment: Do you see the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30315345) link under the question? To add useful information to the question **in a readable way** click that and add to your question. Afterall thats where people will expect to see all the relevant info

Comment: Well `$val = $_POST['location'];` is not a number maybe you meant to use `$val = count($_POST['location']);` But a foreach woudl be so much simpler

Comment: can you show me a sample code using foreach?

Comment: The field and therefore the variable in $_POST is `order_id` and not `id` PLEASE Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Can you please clarify what you actually want here, when you say _"make array output like this"_? Do you just want $_POST to _have_ a specific structure, or do you want to create something new from it (some output to be shown to the user, something that is actually JSON maybe, ...)?

Comment: post array data will be retrieved and rearranged into `['lcoation'=>['msg'=>'order_id']]` then parameterized using http_build_query

Comment: @CBroe if using array_combine something like this:
`$arr1 = array_combine($_POST['msg'], $_POST['order_id']);
$arr2= array_combine($_POST['location'], $arr1);`
but it's impossible, and throws an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made some simple errors

You can foreach over an array then you dont care how large or small it is. You also have a error in the variable used in $_POST.

Using the `foreach( $arr as $index => $value)` syntax gets you an index into the array you are processing, If all 3 arrays are always the same size you can then use that to reference the other arrays.

```
$arr = [];
foreach ( $_POST['location'] as $i => $locn ) {
    $arr[$locn][] = [ $_POST['msg'][$i] => $_POST['order_id'][$i] ];
}
```

It help to debug your code if you

> Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
> top of your file(s) *while testing* right after your opening PHP tag for example.
> Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors.
> `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: thank you sir, seems to work